# Small CSS issue with my main menu?

Tags: css, menu

The site I've made is at www.marigolds-cleaners.co.uk.

As you can see the menu looks fine in firefox and all the other browsers I've tested in, but for some reason there is padding or margin or something that is creating space between the menu links and the pink line at the bottom.

What is causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the padding in the outer div

```
#block-system-main-menu {
padding: 0 0 2px 0;
```

Once you remove the padding, it will be fine

```
#block-system-main-menu {
padding: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#block-system-main-menu .menu li {
    float: left;
    list-style-image: url("../images/bullet.png");
    margin: 0 4%;
}
```

with this code looking nice in my browsers